# Not able to grow the partition of an img file

Tags: bash, fdisk, parted

I have an img file with below partition table

```
$ sudo parted tmp/disk.img 
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /tmp/disk.img
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model:  (file)
Disk /tmp/disk.img: 969MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      512B    67.1MB  67.1MB  primary  fat16        esp
 2      67.1MB  902MB   835MB   primary               boot
 3      902MB   969MB   67.1MB  primary  fat32
```

I have increased the disk using the `dd` command:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=4096 >> /tmp/disk.img
```

now I need to increase the partition 3 using `parted` command:

```
$ sudo parted /tmp/disk.img resizepart 3 1300MB
Error: The location 1300MB is outside of the device /tmp/disk.img.
```

Can I get some clues on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to Ubuntu or any of its derivatives.

Comment: can you help me know which is the right place to post such a query?

Comment: You can just search for it, for example: https://superuser.com/questions/610819/how-to-resize-img-file-created-with-dd?noredirect=1 Was that so hard?

Comment: Thanks but the issue which you posted for reference is not exactly same.  Here I want to grow, a fat32 (msdos) file system, unattended via a script. ..  It has a different use case. If server fault is the right place then I can happy to post it there.